# Drag and drop web items

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I want to build a site where i can make some drag and drop elements on my website. 
I want it to be something like the wordpress widgets. If the user wants to add another text box to a div area they can just drag it to that catagory and it adds an area to add text to there site.

I would like to to be all drag and drop but if they have to choose from a drop down where they want to send it (like box1 or box2 or box3) and then click a button that says add then that would be fine too.

How do i do this or is there a pre made one i can use?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you searched Google? [jQuery Draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) comes up right away.

Comment: @JayBlanchard yes i found that but how do i use this to add elements for a field/div and save it to the db?

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.I would suggest that you find a development forum (perhaps [quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when you have specific coding issues, come back to StackOverflow and we'll be glad to help.

Comment: Here is an example of what im looking for. [Example click here](http://freeemaileditor.com/edit/default.asp?n=3965)

Comment: That is not the way SO works @Donavon. Please read [how to ask questions on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I know how SO works, Thats why im hear. Im not trying to reinvent the wheel. All im asking is if there was anyone that knows of a and i quote "pre made one" that i dont know about or have not found yet.

Comment: One of the reasons to close a question is, ***"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and drop items into something like a div. I found some information here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_draganddrop.asp.